# Как задать иконку для Cluster Markers

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api

Есть много маркеров. Добавляются через класстер. Но в зависимости от `title` иконка должна меняться. Как изменить иконку в класстерах?

Comment: https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/demo/src/com/google/maps/android/utils/demo/CustomMarkerClusteringDemoActivity.java